# How can I programmatically control a browser such as chrome in linux and execute javascript per each tab?

Tags: linux, browser, automation

I have been given a task of toggling nearly 200 users' permissions in an admin. I have access to the database, and I'm sure I can do this in SQL but I'm curious to find out how to do it this way as well, plus I suspect it will be less work because I don't have to study the SQL that's going on and I know exactly what to do after I get access to the browser instance and know how to execute javascript programmatically in the context of the web page open.

I basically want to provide a list of urls which will open ( 195 ) and then execute javascript to toggle checkboxes, then submit the form.

As I stated, I want to use firefox or chrome and I'm on linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) does.

Or, if you can do it all while staying on the same page, you can also just type in arbitrary  JS code by hand in the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console or its Chrome equivalent. This could work if combined with some iframe trickery.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, it has built in support for user automation scripts: http://userscripts.wikidot.com/, http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts

Answer (score 0):

I think a cleaner solution would be for you to figure out what is the url and the parameters to pass to do what you need. Then you can just use curl to make those requests.

Comment: I can't pass any parameters, the application won't autofill them.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... which application won't autofill which parameters? I'm talking about writing a script that sends crafted http requests to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CJS Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en). I add a short script take loads a script from my localhost server and executes it. The executed script can also send results back to the server.